# How to memoize method when one of its memoized parameters should be an instance variable

Tags: python, class, python-3.4, memoization

To memoize `f(x)` I can use `functools.lru_cache()`:

```
class A(object):

    def __init(self):
        self.time = 10  # This changes in the various spots in the program

    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def f(self, x):
        # Lots of code
        # ...
        # ...
        return x * some_other_func(self.time)
```

(to my understanding) `lru_cache()` creates a dict with various `x` as keys and their corresponding `f(x)` as values, so that it returns the stored values if I call `f()` with the same argument value, instead of recalculating it. However, this is not what I need.

My goal is to memoize `f()` values for different values of **both** `x` **and** `self.time`.

---

Using the following code achieves my goal:

```
class A(object):

    def __init(self):
        self.time = 10

    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def g(self, x, t):
        # Lots of code
        # ...
        # ...
        return x * some_other_func(self.time)

    def f(self, x):
        return self.g(x=x, t=self.time)
```

Now instead of memoizing `f(x)` directly, I memoize `g()` which is always called with `t=self.time`.

However I am not sure if this is the cleanest solution. I would expect to only use a decorator for memoization and not have to create intermediate methods.

Is there a less messy way to achieve the above? (I will have to do the above for several methods, so I am looking for a solution as clean as possible)

Comment: Even if `self` was in scope when setting default arguments, the default values are ignored by the caching. Either stick with what you have, or implement the cache yourself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I apologize, this is not what I meant. I removed it from the post. What I need is to simply take into account a variable that is not part of the `f()` parameters, but didn't know how to explain it.

Comment: Your solution seems fine to me

Comment: You'll need to write your own memoizing decorator.  You can find plenty of recipes for this by googling, because people used to do it all the time before `lru_cache` was added to the standard library.

Comment: You're already doing that the one obvious way, having a second method that is cached and called by the first one. Otherwise, you'll have to write the custom caching yourself, to take into account the current state of the instance.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I will have to repeat that type of caching for multiple methods. So should i do the custom thing you suggest?

Comment: Yes; `lru_cache` does the simple thing well, but if you need different behaviour you'll have to do that yourself. You probably won't be able to do it as a decorator, as that only sees the method from the outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement this as a method decorator, here's one option that takes the state-relevant attribute names as arguments:

```
from functools import wraps

def stateful_memoize(*attrs):
    """Memoization that respects specified instance state."""
    def decorator(method):
        @wraps(method)
        def wrapper(self, *args):
            state = args + tuple(getattr(self, attr)
                                 for attr in attrs)
            if state not in wrapper.cache:
                wrapper.cache[state] = method(self, *args)
            return wrapper.cache[state]
        wrapper.cache = {}
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

This simple version won't work with keyword method arguments, but otherwise should be fine. In use:

```
>>> class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.time = 10

    @stateful_memoize('time')
    def f(self, x):
        print('Calling f with x={!r}, self.time={!r}'.format(x, self.time))
        return x * self.time

>>> a = A()
>>> a.f(1)
Calling f with x=1, self.time=10
10
>>> a.f(1)
10
>>> a.time = 5
>>> a.f(1)
Calling f with x=1, self.time=5
5
>>> a.time = 10
>>> a.f(1)
10
>>> a.f(2)
Calling f with x=2, self.time=10
20
>>> a.f.cache
{(1, 10): 10, (1, 5): 5, (2, 10): 20}
```